# mix-blend-mode with bootstrap not working in safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari

I'd like to set the blend-modes of a bootstrap-navbar to "difference" but id does not work in Safari ...

```
.navbar{
  background:none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7y3ccomo/12/

However a simple demo works.

```
.blender{
  font-size: 150px;
  color: red;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sqqkccgn/

Anyone have a clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/7y3ccomo/15/?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').hide().fadeIn();
});
```

I noticed that clicking on the preview area of your first example (in OSX Safari) revealed the background.

So I tried adding a javascript / jQuery to hide the body once and `fadeIn()` right after, which shows the background. But `$('body').hide().show()` does not work. Neither does `$('body').fadeIn();`.

I know that it is not an elegant solution at all. I hope that someone else will find a nicer trick or workaround soon.